# Argument-Dependent Lookup Issue when Casting with Decltype or compiler Bug?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, compiler-bug

When using Argument-Dependent Lookup in VC++2010, I casted the argument using `decltype()` and encountered some weird results:

```
template<typename T>
struct Type {
    typedef T type;
};
namespace NSC {
    typedef enum {
        mon
    } DOW;
    void proc1(DOW s, int a) {
        printf("int proc1\n");
    }
    void proc1(DOW s, long long a) {
        printf("long long proc1\n");
    }

}
void p1(int a) {
    printf("int p1\n");
}
void p1(long long a) {
    printf("long long p1\n");
}

long long g;
int h;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NSC::DOW s=(NSC::DOW)0;
    //proc1(s,(decltype(g))4.0);
    proc1(s,(Type<decltype(2LL)>::type)4.0);
    proc1(s,(Type<decltype(2)>::type)4.0);
    p1((decltype(2LL))4);
    p1((decltype(2))4);

    return 0;
}
```

The above executed normally with these results:

```
long long proc1
int proc1
long long p1
int p1
```

Note that `proc1()` was used to show that typecasting works with argument-dependent lookup while `p1()` was to show that typecasting with `decltype()` directly works with normal overloaded functions. But when I uncommented the line:

```
proc1(s,(decltype(g))4.0);
```

(note the cast was also done directly using a `decltype()` instead of through the `Type` template and involved argument-dependent lookup.) The lookup failed:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cpptest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  cpptest.cpp
1>c:\work\cpptest\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(33): error C3861: 'proc1': identifier not found
```

Is the failure due to some intricate details of the lookup rule or just a compiler bug?

Comment: Your code works with MSVC2015 so I guess you should upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just forgetting to do `NSC::proc1` instead?

Comment: Nonanon, NSC::proc1 is not necessary because argument-dependent- lookup was used